# Excel lookup for single and multiple criteria together

Tags: excel

I have 10000 rows of data in excel in column A & B and a new sheet with all data from column A. What i want to do a `VLOOKUP` from sheet 1 to sheet 2. But there are few examples in column A with 2 values in B.

**Example:**

Sheet 1

[image]

In sheet 2 if `VLOOKUP` is done for orange I am expecting 20,30

I have tried single criteria `=VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!a1,false)` which worked for apple

Any suggestions how both the expected results can be done together

Comment: Could you please upload a sample of your data?

Comment: Am not able to upload the excel sheet

Comment: Create some examples with the correct output in excel just copy them, edit your question and paste them here.

Comment: Thank you. I have provided the sample data. If orange is provided the expected data is 20,30

Comment: Both values (20 and 30)  appears in the same cell or there is another row with `orange` in column A and another value in column B?

Comment: If the two values are in column B, then Excel just sees them as a single value? In which case, =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE) should bring back your match as you've described it. Your vlookup formula looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: Apples, orange and pine are in A1,A2 and A4. A3 is blank. In column B, beside apples is 10. Beside orange is 20 and beside the blank is 30. So my expectation is if we give orange the lookup should be 20,30

Comment: In my opinion the best way to achieve your goal is with VBA

Comment: Ok. By any chance do you have a handy code

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? Do you have a license including the `TEXTJOIN()` function?

Comment: Hi. The excel version is 2013 but I don’t think I have the text join function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but here's a solution with the formula:

[image: form1]

Array formula in cell E2 (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((--(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$6),$A$2:$A$6,OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,-1,0))=$D2))*($B$2:$B$6),1))
```

In column F you need to replace "1" (at the very end of the formula) with number "2".

A few notes:

- your data set cannot start in row 1, otherwise OFFSET formula won't work.
- both formulas (columns E & F) are looking for the 1st and 2nd largest number which matches the argument (column D). If the second one doesn't exist, it returns 0.

However, given the size of your data set, it is worth considering a VBA solution.

**Edit: adjusted for column B = text**

Use the following Array formula in cell E2 (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((--(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$6),$A$2:$A$6,OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,-1,0))=$D2))*(ROW($B$2:$B$6)),1)-1)),"")
```

Similar Array formula in cell F2 (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((--(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$6),$A$2:$A$6,OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,-1,0))=$D2))*(ROW($B$2:$B$6)),2)-1)),"")
```

Result:

[image: adjusted]

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your response, but but I am getting #value! Error in  E2

Comment: Could you please check if you're trying to retrieve text value? I.e. if values in column B are text instead of number? If yes, then my formula won't work - it only retrieves numerical values as per your Apple/Orange/Pine example.

Comment: Unfortunately it is text

Comment: Try the adjusted formula (I edited my original post). You need to add ROW and INDEX components to my first formula.